# Want to check JQuery autocomplete has valid data or not upon submit button click in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to validate user input in autocomplete function on button click. If user select proper data from database then it displays successful message else it should show that please select correct data. Currently, the same functionality is working on `response` but I want the same functionality upon submit button click. Anyone please guide me.

```
 $("#txtemployee").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
           $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                  return {
                            value: item.empName,
                            id: item.empId
                        };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
             $("#hiddenempId").val(ui.item.value);
             $("#hiddenempId").val(ui.item.id);

        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {
             $("#message").text("No results found");               
        }
        else {
            $("#message").empty();
        }
    },
        minLength: 3
    });
});
```

The output:
[image]

My `.cshtml` looks:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenFId)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtName, "", new { @class = "error" })                      
     <span id="message"></span>                                    
     <button type="submit" id="submit">Produce Page</button>

 }
```

The `Home` Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(ClsHome clshome) 
{ 
return View(clshome.produceData());
 }
```

Still user can click on `produce page`. I want to restrict user to click on `produce page` button as entered data is invalid. How to achieve this. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button if there no reasult.

```
response: function (event, ui) {
    if (!ui.content.length) {
         $("#message").text("No results found");
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);               
    }
    else {
        $("#message").empty();
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', false); 
    }
```

Or

```
  $("#submit").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
            data: "{ 'prefix':  $("#txtName").val()}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
              return {
                        value: item.empName,
                        id: item.empId
                    };
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

});

Comment: Thank you Deepu. I will try and see the result.

Comment: Hi Deepu, the first part is working but second part is not. And one more thing, in spite of disabling the button, Can we display message upon button click if user enters some random data.please guide me.

Comment: are you able to post data to '/Home/AutoComplete/'

Comment: You can use second method for that.First you check click event is working or not

Comment: if not please try this event

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {});

Comment: I added `$("#msg").html("Enter proper data");` but I am getting `error.POST http://localhost:53987/Home/AutoComplete/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: `error: function (response) {
            debugger;
            $("#msgHorse").html("Enter proper data");
            
        },`

Comment: please share your controller method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163700/discussion-between-raj-and-deepu-dileep).

Comment: I have sent you the method please find that.

Comment: If you feel that this question is useful to future readers then can you please up vote this. Thank you!